# About xkey implementation

Tags: kdb, k

What is the difference between a functional apply approach `.[0!y;();xcols x]`, seen in `xkey`:

```
xkey
k){(#x)!.[0!y;();xcols x]}
```

and a simple function calling: `x xcols 0!y`.

Why is it the function apply preferred in `xkey`?

And a second question about a call to `xcols` from the inside of `k)` context - how is it ever works? I could not do the same for some reason:

```
t:([]a:`a`s`d;b:1 2 3;c:4 5 6)
k).[0!t;();xcols `a`b]
ERROR: 'xcols 
(attempt to use variable xcols without defining/assigning first (or user-defined signal))
```

Comment: When you use k) you are no longer in the .q namespace, so you should use .q.xcols as opposed to xcols

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the functional apply may be for when passing the table by name

```
t:([]a:`a`s`d;b:1 2 3;c:4 5 6)

.[0!t;();xcols[`a`b]]  /this works

`a`b xcols 0!t         /equivalent non functional form works

q)`a`b xcols 0!`t      /this fails when passing `t
'type
  [0]  `a`b xcols 0!`t


q).[0!`t;();xcols[`a`b]]  /though functional form still works with `t


q)`a`b xkey `t            /hence you can use xkey in place
`t
```

Edit:
To include my comment in the answer for completeness, when inside k you should prefix q commands with .q to access them, as this is the namesapce they reside in

```
q)xcols[`a`b]
k){(x,f@&~(f:cols y)in x)#y}[`a`b]
q)\
  .q.xcols`a`b
k){(x,f@&~(f:cols y)in x)#y}[`a`b]
```

Edit 2:
To address your comment, xcols for your example comes down to

```
`a`b`c#t
```

And

```
`a`b`c#`t
```

doesn't work. I don't have much of an explanation for why it doesn't work, except for that is how it is designed. The functional form is telling q to modify the table by applying the take function. But the example above is not an accepted syntax for redefining a table as a re-ordering of its columns.